# How to convert files from Dos to Unix in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert all files to dos to unix format from a folder using VBA excel.

i can find all the files from drive by using following code.

```
Sub list_all_files(myFilepath As String, filecounter() As Variant, counter1 As Integer)
    With Application.FileSearch
    .NewSearch
    .LookIn = myFilepath
    .filename = "*.*"
    counter = 0
        If .Execute(SortBy:=msoSortByLastModified, SortOrder:=msoSortOrderDescending) > 0 Then
        counter1 = .FoundFiles.Count
            For i1 = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
                counter = counter + 1
                filecounter(counter) = .FoundFiles(i1)
            Next i1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

But How to convert arrayof(files). I want to save the files on the same path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) `Application.FileSearch` has been deprecated from xl07 and onwards. You will to run a recursive `Dir` or `FileStystemObject` routine to gets your files instead (2) I presume these are all `txt` files so why are you searching for `*.*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to open each file in turn and run a find-and-replace operation on the input: `vbCrLf` (DOS) goes to `vbLf` (Unix). You'd then have to write that updated file back out to another file... Alternatively, rather than doing this sequentially, you could scan through each file, writing it back to another at the same time but ignoring all the carriage returns.

A quick Google found example code (e.g., [here](http://www.a1vbcode.com/snippet-2938.asp)) to do the trick.